# Inserting text containing braces in pstricks

Tags: pstricks

I'ld love to create a Database-Symbol with pst-dbicons:

```
\rput(5.5,3.25){\database{3.5cm}{2cm}{Datenbank(en)}}
```

The problem is, that there are braces inside of the text. When I remove them, it works, but with the braces - no error - and no icon is drawn.

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you please turn your code snippet into a *complete*, minimal document illustrating the problem?

Comment: to put a `(` into a postscript string you need (at the postscript level) `\(` so try `Datenbank\string\(en\string\)` untested as no MWE supplied in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\database` needs an identifying name for the generated nodes. As default it uses
the text of the third mandatory argument. But brackets do not work, because they
will break the constructed name in PostScript: `/N@Datenbank(en)` is not a name
token anymore. Therefore `\database` provides an optional argument at the end to
specify an identification name:

```
\database{3.5cm}{2cm}{Datenbank(en)}[Datenbanken]
```

Note to implementors: This kind of problems are the reason for introducing `\pdfescapename`,
`\pdfescapestring` and `\pdfescapehex` to pdfTeX that also works in DVI mode.

Package pdfescape also implements the escaping for e-TeX or vanilla TeX.
The drawback is that `\EdefEscapeName`, `\EdefEscapeString` and friends are
not expandable.

This allows an implementor to use arbitrary text for names or strings in PostScript or PDF
that are written in a syntactically correct manner.